# map corresponding elements in a nested list

Tags: python, list, tuples, zip, python-itertools

Input: `[('1', '100'), (False,), (True,), ('1', '100')]`
Output:

```
[('1', False, True, '1'),
 ('100', False, True, '100')]
```

But when I use itertools.product, it gives me a complete cross product

```
In [191]: l
Out[191]: [('1', '100'), (False,), (True,), ('1', '100')]

In [192]: list(itertools.product(*l))
Out[192]: 
[('1', False, True, '1'),
 ('1', False, True, '100'),
 ('100', False, True, '1'),
 ('100', False, True, '100')]
```

All the tuples inside the list will be of equal size or will be of size 1.

I am able to achieve this by doing the below which doesn't look good

```
In [231]: [[l[i][v] if len(l[i]) > v else l[i][0] for i in range(len(l))] for v in range(max(map(len, l)))]
Out[231]: [['1', False, True, '1'], ['100', False, True, '100']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> Input = [('1', '100'), (False,), (True,), ('1', '100')]
>>> Output = [sum([(i,)]+ Input[1:-1]+ [(i,)],()) for i in Input[-1]]
>>> Output
[('1', False, True, '1'), ('100', False, True, '100')]
```